# How to get data in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get the IsAdmin Value with SQL query(This query return 1 line or 0). but i get this error **{"invalide reading Tentative there are no any data present."}**
This is my code

```
        public static bool Login (string iduser, string password, bool IsAdmin)
    {
        bool auth = false;
        string query = string.Format("Select IsAdmin from [user] where iduser = '{0}' AND mdp = '{1}' ;", iduser, password);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader re = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        auth = re.HasRows;
        if (auth) { IsAdmin = re.GetBoolean(0); } // the error is on this line (this line will alow me to get IsAdmin Value If the user exist)
        con.Close();
        return auth;

    }
```

Comment: Maybe someone has hacked your site using SQL Injection and deleted all the users? Also, SqlDataReader is IDisposable.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but the way you are making your SQL query is liable to SQL injection attacks. You should always use parameterized queries.

Comment: Oh this makes me crave to enter a password like `'; drop table [user]; --`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are open to horrible [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Your site will be pwned by hackers the very same second you put it online if you don't use parametrized queries.

Like this:

```
public static bool IsAdmin(string iduser, string password)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = @"
            SELECT IsAdmin 
            FROM [user] 
            WHERE iduser = @iduser AND mdp = @mdp;
        ";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iduser", iduser);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mdp", password);
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            return reader.Read() && reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("IsAdmin"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
re.Read();
```

to move the reader to the first record before attempting to access the data. `re.HasRows` does not cause the reader to move to the first record.

Also, *definitely* use parameterized queries.